# Text padding differs with wrapping

Tags: css

I have a CSS problem that is driving me a bit nuts.

I'm using two different CSS definitions for large/small text that follow one another in a singe page menu. The small text should butt up against the larger text.

When the larger text wraps, the the smaller text is in the correct position. When the larger text does not wrap, then a gap appears.

I've tried with both block and not, with no difference. Current CSS definitions and the menu is on page left at wptest.SiliconStrat.com.

```
.hometopic {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top:4;
margin-bottom:0;
text-decoration: none;
line-height:100%;
display: inline-block;
}

a.hometopic:hover {
color: #B3535E;
}
.hometopicsub {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 0.9em;
margin-top: 0;
line-height: 0.9;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the BR before the .hometopicsub, use float:left (hometopicsub)  and padding-bottom (hometopic)

```
.hometopic {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top:4;
margin-bottom:0;
text-decoration: none;
line-height:100%;
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 8px;
}
a.hometopic:hover {
color: #B3535E;
}
.hometopicsub {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 0.9em;
margin-top: 0;
line-height: 0.9;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Great response.